# Calling a method from another class doesn't return

Tags: objective-c, methods, return, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com. I'm trying to display comments but in order to get the comments I have to get the PFObject from my DetailViewController but it doesn't return the PFObject to CommentsViewController

EDIT

here is all the code. I'm new to objective c so I'm probably doing something stupid

CommentsView Controller

```
#import "CommentsViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "CommentsCell.h"

@interface CommentsViewController (){
    NSArray *commentsArray;
    id commentInstance;
}

@end

@implementation CommentsViewController




- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(commentsQuery)];
    }
    return self;
}







- (void)commentsQuery {

    commentInstance = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    PFObject *tempObj = [commentInstance placeObject];
    PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activity"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"comment"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"place" equalTo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tempObj objectId]]];
    NSLog(@"%@", tempObj);
    [query1 orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            commentsArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[commentsArray count]);
        }
    }];
}



-  (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CommentsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CommentsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *placeObj = [commentInstance placeObject];
    cell.username.text = @"test";
    return cell;
}


@end
```

DetailsViewCOntroller

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "CommentsViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController (){

    CommentsViewController *test;
}

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize place;
@synthesize userPhoto, message, username, checkCount, photo, scroller, commentsTableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    test = [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];
    self.commentsTableView.delegate = test;
    self.commentsTableView.dataSource = test;



    //Adjust the message label box height
    CGSize textSize = [[place objectForKey:@"message"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(201, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];




    userPhoto.file = [place objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    [userPhoto loadInBackground];

    username.text = [place objectForKey:@"username"];
    message.text = [place objectForKey:@"message"];
    checkCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [place objectForKey:@"checkMarkCount"]];
    [message sizeToFit];
    if ([place objectForKey:@"photo"] != Nil){
        photo.file = [place objectForKey:@"photo"];
        [photo loadInBackground];
        //[photo sizeToFit];
        photo.frame = CGRectMake(6, textSize.height + 50, photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height);

        float sizeOfContent = 0;
        UIView *lLast = [scroller.subviews lastObject];
        NSInteger wd = lLast.frame.origin.y;
        NSInteger ht = lLast.frame.size.height;
        NSLog(@"%@", lLast);

        sizeOfContent = wd+ht;
        scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroller.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent+100);
    }
    else{

        float sizeOfContent = 0;
        UIView *lLast = [scroller.subviews lastObject];
        NSInteger wd = lLast.frame.origin.y;
        NSInteger ht = lLast.frame.size.height;
        NSLog(@"%@", lLast);

        sizeOfContent = wd+ht;
        scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroller.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent+100);

    }







}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)checkMarkButton:(UIButton *)sender {
}




- (PFObject *)placeObject{
    return place;
}
@end
```

Comment: Do you have `DetailViewController::init` function? What does it do? Your `placeObject` function is redundant, it duplicates `property place`. You also do not need `synthesize place` directive, compiler does that implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where you allocate `place` object. You call `init` and then try retrieving `place`. It should return nil. Here is your code:

```
commentInstance = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
PFObject *tempObj = [commentInstance placeObject];
```

commentInstance is a new object. There is no init function defined in DetailViewController, hence commentInstance.place is nil and that is returned by placeObject method.

You define place as a property

```
@property ... place
```

That gives you a member variable _pace and two member functions, `place()` and `setPlace(place)`. The object itself is not allocated for you.
Allocate place object in your `init` function, get rid of `placeObject()`, replace it with `object.place` call.

Comment: place is being passed through from the previous view in the prepareForSegue method

Comment: I see what your saying now and I don't think its going to work. Because commentInstance = [[DetailViewController alloc] init]; is creating the new instance but DetailViewController gets the PFObject place from the homepage through a segue. So it will never have the pfobject if I create a new instance of DetailViewController. Is there any way I can pass place onto the CommentsViewController or should I just delete it and create the tableView inside DetailViewController?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking. Certainly, you can pass an object around. If you have `place` at a time of segue then you may pass it in and then further.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of all that and in my DetailViewController I added [test placeSet:place] in my viewDidLoad method. Then in CommentsViewController I did...

```
- (void)placeSet:(PFObject *)object{
    place = object;
    NSLog(@"place = %@", place);
}
```